# Error while launching EC2 instance using terraform

Tags: amazon-ec2, terraform

I am fairly new to Terraform. I am trying to use below Terraform code to launch EC2 instance:

```
provider "aws" {
  region     = "ap-south-1"
  access_key = "<Key>"
  secret_key = "<secret>"
}
# Main VPC
resource "aws_vpc" "vpc_main" {
  cidr_block = "10.0.0.0/16"

  enable_dns_support   = true
  enable_dns_hostnames = true

  tags = {
    Name = "Main VPC"
  }
}

resource "aws_subnet" "public" {
  vpc_id                  = "${aws_vpc.vpc_main.id}"
  cidr_block              = "10.0.0.0/16"
  map_public_ip_on_launch = true
  tags = {
    Name                  = "Public Subnet"
  }
}

resource "aws_security_group" "allow_web" {
  name        = "allow-web-traffic"
  description = "Allow all inbound/outbound traffic on 80 443"
  vpc_id      = "${aws_vpc.vpc_main.id}"

  ingress {
    from_port   = 80
    to_port     = 80
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  ingress {
    from_port = 443
    to_port   = 443
    protocol  = "tcp"
  }

  egress {
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    protocol    = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
}

resource "aws_security_group" "allow_ssh" {
  name        = "allow-ssh-traffic"
  description = "Allow ssh traffic on 22"
  vpc_id      = "${aws_vpc.vpc_main.id}"

  ingress {
    from_port   = 22
    to_port     = 22
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  egress {
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    protocol    = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
}

resource "aws_instance" "proxy_server" {
  ami           = "ami-026f33d38b6410e30" # RHEL 7.5 HVM SSD
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  key_name      = "EC2NewKey"
  security_groups = ["allow_ssh","allow_web"]
  vpc_security_group_ids = ["${aws_security_groups.allow_ssh.id}","${aws_security_group.allow_web.id}"] # this breaks it
  subnet_id     = "${aws_subnet.public.id}"
}
```

But getting an error while executing 'Terraform plan': "A managed resource "aws_security_groups" "allow_ssh" has not been declared in the root module". Can anyone tell me what fundamental error I am doing in the code
?

Comment: You have a typo: the resource is `aws_security_group` and not `groups`.

Answer (score 1):

A typo.

```
aws_security_groups.allow_ssh.id
```

should become:

```
aws_security_group.allow_ssh.id
```